# Key Bindings in Java: Delay after key press

Tags: java, swing, awt, key-bindings

EDIT: Added code from the game.

I got Key Bindings for a game I'm working on. They're supposed to move objects when keys are pressed.

(currently, each println(..) represents actual code to move things on the screen, will be added later).

The printing in the console works, but with delays. The words "left", "right", etc. appear with a delay in the console, sometimes half a second delay, sometimes a few seconds delay.

There is no delay at all sometimes, but when a lot of keys are pressed one after the other, there's a delay of several seconds, and only then the words appear in the console (like the computer had too much to handle at the same time).

When I did the same Key Bindings in a different project without all the game logic, only pressing buttons that print words in the console - it worked perfectly without delay.

So I suspect the problem is something with the game code, or the way I used Key Bindings inside the game code.

How do I fix this?

I tried putting the Key Bindings code in the thread that contains the game-loop (before the game-loop), and in the constructor. Same problem.

Here is the relevant code of the Board class (extending JPanel), the main JPanel of the game which displays the graphics and manipulates objects.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Board extends JPanel implements Runnable {

    Tank tank1,tank2;
    boolean[] keysPressed1,keysPressed2;
    Action upAction,leftAction,rightAction,wAction,aAction,dAction;
    InputMap inputMap;
    ActionMap actionMap;

    public Board(){

        setFocusable(true);
        setBackground(Color.BLACK);

        tank1 = new Tank("red");
        tank2 = new Tank("blue");

        inputMap = this.getInputMap();
        actionMap = this.getActionMap();

        Thread gameloop = new Thread(this);
        gameloop.start();

    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){

        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

        // Drawing tanks on the screen.

    }

    public void run(){

        // Key Bindings //////

        upAction = new AbstractAction(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                System.out.println("up");
            }
        };

        leftAction = new AbstractAction(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                System.out.println("left");
            }
        };

        rightAction = new AbstractAction(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                System.out.println("right");
            }
        };

        wAction = new AbstractAction(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                System.out.println("w");
            }
        };

        aAction = new AbstractAction(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                System.out.println("a");
            }
        };

        dAction = new AbstractAction(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                System.out.println("d");
            }
        };

        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("UP"),"upAction");
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("LEFT"),"leftAction");
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("RIGHT"),"rightAction");
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("W"),"wAction");
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("A"),"aAction");
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("D"),"dAction");

        actionMap.put("upAction",upAction);
        actionMap.put("leftAction",leftAction);
        actionMap.put("rightAction",rightAction);
        actionMap.put("wAction",wAction);
        actionMap.put("aAction",aAction);
        actionMap.put("dAction",dAction);

            // End Key Bindings //////

            // Start of game loop. ////

        int TICKS_PER_SECOND = 50;
        int SKIP_TICKS = 1000 / TICKS_PER_SECOND;
        int MAX_FRAMESKIP = 10;

        long next_game_tick = System.currentTimeMillis();
        int loops;

        boolean game_is_running = true;

        while( game_is_running ) {

            loops = 0;
            while( System.currentTimeMillis() > next_game_tick && loops < MAX_FRAMESKIP) {

                    // Code to manipulate tank1.
                    // .......

                tank1.move();

                    // Code to manipulate tank2.
                    // .......

                tank2.move();

                next_game_tick += SKIP_TICKS;
                loops++;
            }

            repaint();
        }

    }
}
```

Thank you for the help

Comment: Consider posting a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) for better help.

Comment: It would be easier for us to answer your question if you showed us the important parts of you game code (exactly where and how you put in your Key Bindings code).

Comment: Chances are there's something happening that means the thread isn't executing it straight away, but the code you've posted here is largely irrelevant - we'll need to see a SSCCE to help further.

Comment: I edited the question significantly and posted only the (I think) relevant code. Help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Can we compile and run your code un-altered? No. So it's not an SSCCE, and many of us will not be able to help. If you don't get an answer soon, consider creating and posting your SSCCE.

Answer (score 1):

- You are doing a lot of Swing calls off of the Swing event thread or EDT. If you want to be prudent (you do, trust me), don't do this.
- You're relying on the OS to do repetitive actions when a key is held down, and the OS's behavior is to first pause before repeating.
- You need to start a Swing Timer on key press and turn it off or change its state on key raise. This will likely solve your problem.

If this doesn't help, again consider putting in the effort to create and post an [sscce](http://sscce.org).

Comment: By "swing calls" you mean, any command that affects a Swing component?
If so, the only "swing calls" I found are these:
setFocusable(true);
setBackground(Color.BLACK);
Are there any more?

Comment: There is indeed the built-in delay you're talking about, but not only that. I edited this into the question: "There is no delay at all sometimes, but when a lot of keys are pressed one after the other, there's a delay of several seconds, and only then the words appear in the console (like the computer had too much to handle at the same time)."
It's like the program demands too much of the computer, so the computer can't print the words "left","right",etc. without a delay sometimes. Any idea how to fix this?